# String and text files java

Tags: java

I'm studying for finals and I'm trying to do the following:

Open the file nFile, and print the string that corresponds to line number start to line number finish, in the file nameFile.

Must handle error message when the line number start or finish do not exist, should print the string "Line not found" if an IOException occurs, the method should print "IO Error".

I'm using a text file with the following:

```
11 
1c20 
203 
G2
```

If 2,4 is entered,  "1c20 203 G2". will be printed

I have researched a lot and I'm stuck on printing the strings when a line number is entered.

```
import java.io.*;

public class files { 
public void dR(String nFile, int start, int finish)     
{
        try{                
               FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("C://rest//dat.txt");

               // Get the object of DataInputStream
               DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
               BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

               nameFile=null;
               start=0;
               finish=0;
                // if start  is greater or = to 1 and finish less than 4
                while((nFile=br.readLine())!=null && start>= 1 && finish <= 4)
                {
                     for(int i=0; i<=start; i++)
                     {
                         System.out.println(nFile);
                         br.close();
                     }
                     System.out.println("that doesnt exsist"); 
                  }            
      } 
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                 System.out.println("there is an IO error");                
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Finals of what? You don't stick to naming conventions? Looks more like a beginner. nameFile isn't declared - don't you have a compiler? Start and finish are passed as parameter but you overwrite them with 0 - why? What shall dR mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are throwing away all input you get from the parameter

```
int linenb=1;//this will hold the current line number
while((nFile=br.readLine())!=null){
    if(linenb>=start&&linenb<=finish)  
        System.out.println(nfile); 
    linenb++;
}
if(linenb<=finish)
    System.out.println("Line not found");
```

also add a finally block that will do the close

Answer (score 1):

something like this?

```
for (int i=1 ; (nFile=br.readLine())!=null; i++) 
{
 if (start>= i && finish <= i)
 {
  System.out.println(nFile);
 }
}
br.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, you aren't using the `nFile` parameter (hint: it's the file name. Guess where it should go in your code...), and in these two lines:

```
start=0;
finish=0;
```

You just lost the parameters that were given to you.

Instead, I would make a new variable

```
int index = 0;
```

increment it with each new line, and if it is between start and finish, print out the line.

You still need to "read" the lines that are before `start` to be able to count which line you are on.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class printStrings
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

        int start = in.nextInt ();
        int stop = in.nextInt ();

        ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String> ();
        String line = null;
        BufferedReader buff = null;
        try
        {
            buff = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (new FileInputStream ("data.txt")));
            while ((line = buff.readLine ()) != null)
            {
                strings.add (line);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println ("IO Error");
            System.exit (-1);
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                buff.close ();
            }
            catch (IOException e2) {}
        }

        if (start < 1 || start > strings.size () || stop < 1 || stop > strings.size () || start > stop)
        {
            System.err.println ("Line not found");
            System.exit (-2);
        }

        for (int i = start - 1; i < stop; i++)
        {
            System.out.println (strings.get (i));
        }
    }
}
```